# is it possible to convert matlab fitnet neural network to keras

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras

I would like to convert a matlab code for neural network to Keras

From something like:

```
net = fitnet([6,6,6],'trainbr');
net = train(net,x,t);
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,y,t)
```

to something like:

```
nb_cols = len(x.columns)
num_class_output = 6
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6, activation="relu", input_shape=(nb_cols, )))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_class_output, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, t)
```

The first problem is that 'trainbr' is for Bayesian Regularization, how to do that with Keras ?

Do you think this could be a good way to do that ?

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699503/how-to-convert-to-keras-code-from-matlab-deep-learning-model

Comment: thank you but it seems that I don't have the same kind of NN than on this post 
I am looking for the fitnet equivalent